# R How to Check if XPath Exists

Tags: r, xpath, web-scraping

hoping someone more knowledgeable than me can throw some light here.

As part of a larger web-scraper I want to pull meta data out of a set of pages.  When I ran this it fell over, investigation shows this was due to one of the Xpath's being requested not existing.

I can see one potential solution is to grab ALL the meta for a page into a vector and to check if each required one exists before building a new vector of just those I want.

BUT

It would be even better if I only grabbed the bits I want if they exist in the page.

```
require(XML)
require(RCurl)
parsed <- htmlParse("http://www.coindesk.com/information")

meta <- list()
meta[1] <- xpathSApply(parsed, "//meta[starts-with(@property, \"og:title\")]", xmlGetAttr,"content")
meta[2] <- xpathApply(parsed, "//meta[starts-with(@property, \"og:description\")]", xmlGetAttr,"content")
meta[3] <- xpathApply(parsed, "//meta[starts-with(@property, \"og:url\")]",  xmlGetAttr,"content")
meta[4] <- xpathApply(parsed, "//meta[starts-with(@property, \"article:published_time\")]",  xmlGetAttr,"content")
meta[5] <- xpathApply(parsed, "//meta[starts-with(@property, \"article:modified_time\")]",  xmlGetAttr,"content")
```

This will throw an error as `og:description` isn't in this page.

```
Error in meta[2] <- xpathApply(parsed, "//meta[starts-with(@property, \"og:description\")]",  : 
  replacement has length zero
```

Can anyone suggest a simple test that will check for its existence before trying to extract it, falling over gracefully with perhaps a NULL response?

Comment: What error do you get? When I run your code I get an empty list.

Comment: Me too, even when I fix the double-quote in the `htmlParse` line which makes me doubly-suspicious that this code doesn't produce that problem.

Comment: Sorry chaps, I hastely posted the question before getting dragged out the door by the Missus, far from happy I was doing "work stuff" when I am supposed to be on holiday.

Yes I picked up on the double quotes and removed those.  Jdharrison - I think you are right, it returns an empty list, and I am not handling that.

This is only day four of coding FULL STOP, and it's been a steep learning curve.  Spacedman's length test will obviously do the job.  Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the error comes when you try and process the empty list...

```
> parsed <- htmlParse("http://www.coindesk.com/information")
> meta <- xpathApply(parsed, "//meta[starts-with(@property, \"og:description\")]", xmlGetAttr,"content")
> meta
list()
> length(meta)==0
[1] TRUE
```

Then test for `length(meta)==0` - which is `TRUE` if the element is missing. Otherwise its `FALSE` - as in this example of extracting the title property:

```
> meta <- xpathApply(parsed, "//meta[starts-with(@property, \"og:title\")]", xmlGetAttr,"content")
> meta
[[1]]
[1] "Beginner's guide to bitcoin - CoinDesk's Information Center"

> length(meta)==0
[1] FALSE
```

Comment: can you explain the syntax of the backslashes, as in \"og:description\?  I am not versed in xpath, but heretofore I thought forward slashes or double forward slashes, were path locators.

Comment: Those are just escaping the quote marks because the R string is being enclosed within quote marks. The backslashes aren't actually in the string.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this has been hard to nail down.  Whilst there are a couple of custom implementations of xpathApply knocking around that handle NULL results the solution to the question posed did lay in Spacedman's suggestion.

The first part of the `IF` statement calls the xPath and checks to see if the return length = 0.
If it does then it applies a custom message to the list, "Title NA" or "Description NA" but
if the length isn't 0 (i.e. there is a match) then it applies the xPath to the list.

Simples.

```
 require(XML)
    require(RCurl)
    parsed <- htmlParse("http://www.coindesk.com/information")

    meta    <- list()
    meta[1] <- if(length(xpathSApply(parsed, "//meta[starts-with(@property, \"og:title\")]", xmlGetAttr,"content"))==0) 
               {
                 "Title NA"
               } 
               else 
               {
                 xpathSApply(parsed, "//meta[starts-with(@property, \"og:title\")]", xmlGetAttr,"content")
               }
    meta[2] <- if(length(xpathApply(parsed, "//meta[starts-with(@property, \"og:description\")]", xmlGetAttr,"content"))==0) 
               {  
                 "Description NA" 
               } 
               else 
               {
                  xpathApply(parsed, "//meta[starts-with(@property, \"og:description\")]", xmlGetAttr,"content")
               }
```