# R List with List, Checking for xPath before applying

Tags: r, xpath, web-scraping

Moving on from an earlier question I posed on "[How to Check if XPath Exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25502583/r-how-to-check-if-xpath-exists/25553805#25553805)" I've hit a weird quirk which has me stumped.

Given the following code, why is it that the test for meta[2] works fine, BUT when testing for meta[3] it always returns an empty item.

Can anyone explain why / fix this?  Cheers

```
require(XML)
require(RCurl)

urls      <- list("http://www.coindesk.com/information")
for (i in seq_along(urls)) 
{
  parsed  <- htmlParse(urls[i])
  meta    <- list()
  meta[1] <- urls[i]
  meta[2] <- if(length(xpathApply(parsed, "//meta[starts-with(@property, \"og:description\")]", xmlGetAttr,"content"))==0) 
             {  
               "Desc NA" 
             } 
             else 
             {
               xpathApply(parsed, "//meta[starts-with(@property, \"og:description\")]", xmlGetAttr,"content")
             }    
  meta[3]  <- if(length(paste(xpathApply(parsed, "//meta[starts-with(@property, \"article:tag\")]", xmlGetAttr,"content"), collapse = ','))==0) 
             {
               "Tags NA"
             } 
             else 
             {
               paste(xpathApply(parsed, "//meta[starts-with(@property, \"article:tag\")]", xmlGetAttr,"content"), collapse = ',')   
             }
}
print(meta)

[[1]]
[1] "http://www.coindesk.com/information"

[[2]]
[1] "Desc NA"

[[3]]
[1] ""
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are adding the `paste()`. Note that when the `xpathApply` doesn't find anything it returns `list()` which has length 0. However when you use that in paste

```
paste(list(), collapse=",")
# [1] ""
```

it actually returns a vector of length 1 with an empty string. It would be best to take the `paste()` out of the `if`

```
 if(length(xpathApply(parsed, "//meta[starts-with(@property, \"article:tag\")]", xmlGetAttr,"content"))==0)
```

Comment: Can't believe I didn't try that. Duh.  Ah well guess I'm still only in week one of coding in anything.

The test works just fine without the paste, and then in the length!=0 case putting it back in solves it.  Brilliant.