# For loop skip if table does not exist

Tags: r, xpath

Ran in to another problem.  I have a for loop that contains urls to scrape batting information from a table with the id batting_gamelogs.  If that id does not exist on the page then move on to the next url else scrape the table.

I think it should be something like this below, but I can't get it to work.

```
 if xpathSApply(batting, '//*[@id != "batting_gamelogs"]')[[1]] next

 else
    {
 tableNode <- xpathSApply(batting, '//*[@id="batting_gamelogs"]')[[1]]
    data <- readHTMLTable(tableNode, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    data # select the first table
    total <- cbind(id,year,data)

    batlist <- rbind(batlist, total)

    }
```

I have attached sample code.

```
#SCRAPE BATTING STATS

data = NULL
batlist = NULL

battingURLs <- paste("http://www.baseball-reference.com",yplist[,c("hrefs")],sep="")

for(thisbattingURL in battingURLs){

batting <- htmlParse(thisbattingURL)

fstampid <- regexpr("&", thisbattingURL, fixed=TRUE)-1
fstampyr <- regexpr("year=", thisbattingURL, fixed=TRUE)+5
id <- substr(thisbattingURL, 53, fstampid)
year <- substr(thisbattingURL, fstampyr, 75)

tableNode <- xpathSApply(batting, '//*[@id="batting_gamelogs"]')[[1]]
data <- readHTMLTable(tableNode, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
data # select the first table
total <- cbind(id,year,data)

batlist <- rbind(batlist, total)

}

batlist
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can't get it to work.

This phrase should always be a reminder to tell what actually happened (and how it differs from what you expected to happen). I suspect what happened was that it skipped too often (vs. not skipping when it should have). But you could tell us that, instead of leaving us to figure it out.

```
if xpathSApply(batting, '//*[@id != "batting_gamelogs"]')[[1]] next
```

The "not" is in the wrong place. Here, you're saying, skip this iteration if there is an element on the page that has an `id` attribute whose value is not `batting_gamelogs`. Instead you want to skip this iteration if there is *no* element on the page that has an `id` attribute whose value *is* `batting_gamelogs`.

So, use this for your XPath expression:

```
'//*[@id = "batting_gamelogs"]'
```

and put the "not" outside of `xpathSApply()`, by testing whether the length of the result list is zero (thanks to the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/25553805/423105):

```
if (length(xpathSApply(batting, '//*[@id = "batting_gamelogs"]')) == 0) next
```

I took out the `[[1]]` because you just want to test whether any values are returned; you don't care about extracting the first result.

Comment: Thanks @LarsH for your help, really appreciate it!!  Your post makes complete sense, but I get 2 errors now, 

1 at the xpathSApply

*code*+ if ! xpathSApply(batting, '//*[@id = "batting_gamelogs"]')[[1]] next
Error: unexpected '!' in:
"
if !"*code*

and the very last }

*code*> }
Error: unexpected '}' in "}"*code*

I'm sorry if I overlooked something really stupid, I'm new to the R language.  Thanks again!

Comment: @Don: I'm new to R too... I'm more of an XPath guy. So, apologies for the mistakes and thanks for posting the error messages. I've updated the above to something that's more likely to work, but I don't have environment for testing R. So if it still doesn't work, I'm not really equipped to fix the R side of the problem. What's needed is to test the output from xpathSApply() and determine whether anything is returned.

Comment: @Don: updated my answer again based on http://stackoverflow.com/a/25503686/423105

Comment: Perfect @larsh!  Thank you!  I'm sorry I didn't didn't find the post you did. Not sure why my searches didn't turn that one up, but I kept searching for tables. Thanks again!